# Let $p(n)=\frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{4})^n$ with $n=0,1,2,...$ the function or discrete random variable of $X$. Find the distribution function of $X$

Tags: probability

Good afternoon, i have a doubt with this exercise. Thanks for take the time in read my question.

Let $p(n)=\frac{3}{4}(\frac{1}{4})^n$ with $n=0,1,2,...$ the function or discrete random variable of $X$. Find the distribution function of $X$

**My Work:**

Let $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function of distribution.

If $n<0$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq n)=0$
If $n=0$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq 0)=\frac{3}{4}$
If $0<n<1$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq n)=\frac{3}{4}$
If $n=1$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq 1)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4^2}$
If $1<n<2$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq n)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4^2}$
If $n=2$ then $F(n)=P(X\leq n)=\frac{3}{4}+\frac{3}{4^2}+\frac{3}{4^3}$

Then, i think $F(n)=P(X\leq n)=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\frac{1}{4})^n$

is this good?

Comment: Good start, but I expect you are meant to evaluate that sum.  You should, for instance, be able to confirm that $\lim_{n\to \infty} F(n)=1$.

Comment: @lulu that serie is a geometric serie and converge because $r<1$

Comment: @Bvss12 You are correct, of course -- but you may need to show that it converges **to 1**, not just that it converges.

Comment: True.  As I said, my guess would be that you are meant to write out the closed form for the partial sums and check what happens at $\infty$.

Comment: Ready, $\lim_{n\to \infty} F(n)=\frac{3}{4}\frac{4}{3}=1$ because $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}$ then with this, the exercise is good? @lulu

Comment: One more comment: your final expression for $F(n)$ appears not to be a function of $n$ at all. For instance, how could I use it to evaluate $F(5)$?

Comment: $F(5)=(\frac{3}{4})+(\frac{3}{4})^2+(\frac{3}{4})^3+(\frac{3}{4})^4+(\frac{3}{4})^5+(\frac{3}{4})^6$ @AaronMontgomery

Comment: @Bvss12 That's certainly correct, but it doesn't appear in your expression for $F(n)$ in your last line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**As one solution**:
First check that the probability mass function (pmf) is valid. That is, check the following holds:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {p(n)}=1$$
Now $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}$$
Note that, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}$$ is a geometric series in the form  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {ar^n}$ where $a=1$ is the first term and $r=\frac{1}{4}$ is the common ratio, where $\left|r\right|=\frac{1}{4}\lt1$. In this case, the sum to infinitity is given by $S_\infty=a\frac{1}{1-r}$.

Therefore:
$$\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}=\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right)=\frac{3}{4}\left(\frac{4}{4-1}\right)=\frac{3}{3}=1$$. 
Hence, since the sum of the probabilities add to $1$, the above pmf is valid for all $n=0,1,2,3,...$

To find the distribution (CDF), use the the fact that if a geometric series is given by $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {ar^n}$, then the sum of the first $n$ terms is given by
$$S_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}{ar^k}=a\left(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r}\right)$$

Hence, if let the distribution function be denotes as $F_x(x)$ then
$$F_x(n)=P(X\le{n})=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{k=0}^n {\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n}=\frac{3}{4}\left[\frac{1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{4}}\right]=1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}$$
Therefore,
$$F_x(n)=1-\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n+1}$$

Finally, note the use of $n+1$ instead of $n$ to calculate the distribution function.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Consider $F(n) = 1-P(X > n)$. Since $P(X > n)$ involves the infinite series, the expression can be simplified much easier than looking at the finite sum. Although, the finite sum is not so bad either being the partial sum of a geometric series.